# default value with select case on xml

Tags: sql-server, transaction, xml, xquery

```
select case 'NULL' when 'NULL' then 'f' end as out
```

output: **f**

but

```
select case (select  (SELECT LEFT(l.list,LEN(l.list)-1) 
    FROM
    (SELECT  o.Reciting_Path + '|' + o.Declaimer +',' AS [text()]
    FROM    Poetry_Reciting  AS o
    where   o.Poetry_Id=6764
    FOR XML PATH(''))l(list)) )  when  'NULL' then 'N' end as dd
```

should just return **NULL** and NULL is correct but the case statement does not work.

I want 'N' in output

Comment: How could the output be `1`? Shouldn't it be `f`? Also what is the point of performing all of that concatenation if you're never going to use the output? Wouldn't just checking for the existence of those values be sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two points of confusion here.

The first is that you seem to think `'NULL'` and `NULL` are the same; they're not. The former is a string literal, the latter merely signifies the absence of a value.

The second is that you can use `NULL` in equality comparisons; and you cannot. Try this:

```
SELECT CASE NULL WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Result:

```
----
0
```

The reason is that `NULL` is unknown - so SQL Server can't tell you whether it is *or is not* equal to a specific value (or even to another `NULL` value). To check if a value is `NULL`, you can't say `CASE WHEN value = NULL` or `CASE value WHEN NULL`, but you can say `CASE WHEN value IS NULL`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Result:

```
----
1
```

Now, I think there are better ways to accomplish what you *seem* to need (I'm not confident I understand the requirements here at all), but in the immediate term you can correct this by saying:

```
select case WHEN (select ... )  IS NULL then 'N' end as dd;
```